# firestore: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions expo

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, expo, firebase-security

I have an old application that was developed 2 years ago. it is working fine on old devices. no I want to upgrade it for new devices. so I updated firebase from 8.2.3 to 10.7.0. no when ever I add , get or delete some data form the firestorm it say insufficient permission or access denied. I have made the rules public ie. in development also have non access.

here are my rules.

```
// Allow read/write access to all users under any conditions
// Warning: **NEVER** use this rule set in production; it allows
// anyone to overwrite your entire database.
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

My initialization code:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore} from 'firebase/firestore';
import {getStorage} from 'firebase/storage';
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "xxxx",
  authDomain: "xxxx.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "project_id",
  storageBucket: "32323232dsdsds",
  messagingSenderId: "3232323",
  appId: "1:32323:web:32323232323232"
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);
const storage = getStorage(app)
export  {db}
export {storage}
```

here is how I get data

```
  const fetchData = async () => {
        try {
            const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, 'Sudddy-data'));
            const docs = [];
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                docs.push({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() });
            });
            setFormData(docs);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('Error fetching data:', error);
        }
    };
  useEffect(()=>{
    fetchData();
  },[])
```

Comment: Try adding `rules_version = '2';` to the top of your rules file. If the problem persists, I recommend using the Rules Playground on Firestore to debug.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using firestore rules v2 but you did not specify it. Try adding `rules_version = '2';` to the top of your rules file. If the problem persists, I recommend using the Rules Playground on Firestore to debug.

Reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started#security_rules_version_2

Comment: I have identified the issue. the firebase was enforced for region app specific . so I was not able to get data.